# Updated to Android Studio and now receiving AAPT: error: resource attr/type not found error for Navigation

Tags: android, gradle, aapt, aapt2

I just updated to Android Studio 3.6.1 and the most up-to-date gradle versions and now my project won't build with the error

```
.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2/<some-hash-number>/navigation-common-1.0.0-alpha01/res/values/values.xml:16:5-21-25: AAPT: error: resource attracts/type not found
```

I attempted to clear my cache and rebuild, but it didn't help. So I also tried a Invalidate Caches and Restart, and that also didn't change anything. Not sure what else to try...

EDIT: Added Values.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="NavAction">
        <attr name="android:id"/>
        <attr format="reference" name="destination"/>
        <attr format="boolean" name="launchSingleTop"/>
        <attr format="boolean" name="launchDocument"/>
        <attr format="boolean" name="clearTask"/>
        <attr format="reference" name="popUpTo"/>
        <attr format="boolean" name="popUpToInclusive"/>
        <attr format="reference" name="enterAnim"/>
        <attr format="reference" name="exitAnim"/>
        <attr format="reference" name="popEnterAnim"/>
        <attr format="reference" name="popExitAnim"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NavArgument">
        <attr name="android:name"/>
        <attr name="android:defaultValue"/>
        <!--free format since in future it could be Parcelable-->
        <attr name="type"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NavDeepLink">
        <attr format="string" name="uri"/>
        <attr name="android:autoVerify"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="NavGraphNavigator">
        <attr format="reference" name="startDestination"/>
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="Navigator">
        <attr name="android:id"/>
        <attr name="android:label"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Android Studio 3.6. To fix it, I had to add the format of my custom view attributes in my `attrs.xml` file. E.g.

```
<declare-styleable name="TheCustomView">
    <attr name="custom_view_attribute" />
</declare-styleable>
```

became:

```
<declare-styleable name="TheCustomView">
    <attr name="custom_view_attribute" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: The strange part is that this is a result of Android's Navigation library, not my own Custom View...

Comment: FYI: this `format` requirement is introduced by Gradle update (probably since 6.1.1 and plugin 4.0.0), not Android Studio itself

Comment: This was with plugin version 3.6.3, so I think it has to do with that instead.